# NSCoding and restoring views

Tags: ios, uiview, nscoding

I have just restored some UIImageView objects with -`(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder.` However I try and add them back into my view and I see nothing. Does UIImageView lose the frame and image it is assigned to when saved using NSCoding?

Comment: You have offered confusing information.  Did you write extensions or did you create subclasses?  Did you implement your own version of `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageView` conforms to `NSCoding`, as does `UIView`, so between your `UIImageView`, its subviews, and their properties, everything probably conforms to NSCoding except for the actual `UIImage`.

You would need to separately encode it like:

```
[encoder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image) forKey:@"image"];
```

And the retrieve it like:

```
self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"image"]];
```

And then set it to your image view.

**Edit** Post OP comment:

Frame is based on the parents coordinate system and there is no parent until you add the view. If you have a subclass you could override the coding methods and store the frame yourself, although it might not end up being in the right position based on the parent view.

Comment: does the frame need coding too?

Comment: You cannot preserve frame for the reason I mentioned in my post. However you can try saving the values and use them later.

Comment: thanks. I noticed you don't even have to set the image. remains set.